# ListView scrolls to top after updating it

Tags: android, listview, scroll, autoscroll

I have a `mChildEventListener` that queries for the first **n** items from `Firebase Database` and another `mChildEventListener2`  (triggered when the user scroll up and clicks on a `Load More` button) that queries for the next **n** items and adds them to the `ChatMessagesList`.

When the user clicks on the `Load More` button: the `ChatMessagesList` is updated and `notifyDataSetChanged` is called. The `mMessageListView` is updated but it scrolls down to the buttom every time. I explained this behavior because of the xml attribute: `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"`.

When I remove `transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` and the user presses on the `Load More` button, the `mMessageListView` scrolls this time to the top.

None of these behaviors are wanted. I would like that when the user presses the button, the `mMessageListView` would maintain its' scrolling position. (for obvious reasons)

I tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from a new thread. No results.

I tried using `listView.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewedPosition, topOffset);` or using `list.smoothScrollToPosition();` but none achieved a smooth experience that I would want.

**How can I maintain the scrolling position after the `mMessageListView` is updated?**

This is the code:

```
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener2;

List<ChatMessage> ChatMessages = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message_sent, ChatMessages);
mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

 mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    current_last_key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                }
                else {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                    mMessageAdapter.add(chatMessage);
                }
                i++;
            }
          ...
        };
        Query messagesQuery =  mDatabaseReference.child("chat_messages").
                child(chatId).limitToLast(25);
        messagesQuery.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
          ...
   }

 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    j = 0;
    mChildEventListener2 = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(current_last_key)) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    current_last_key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                }
                else {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                    ChatMessages.add(j- 1, chatMessage);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                ChatMessage chatMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatMessage.class);
                ChatMessages.add(0 , chatMessage);
                loadMoreTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            j++;
        }

        ...        };
    Query query = mDatabaseReference.child("chat_messages").
            child(chatId).orderByKey().endAt(current_last_key).limitToLast(10);
    query.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

Try to see if "onCreate()" is called again when updating

Comment: I don't see the relevance. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

[FirebaseUI lib](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md) handles all that for you and simplifies your code.
BTW, you can use `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(ChatMessages.size() - 1);` or `mMessageAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(ChatMessages.size() - 1, ChatMessages.size() - 1 + numberOfItemsBeingInserted);` and make the other required changes in order for this to work, instead of using `mMessageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: You mean  FirebaseUI lib handles data paginating?

Comment: Yes! Just use `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter(Class<T> modelClass,
                                        @LayoutRes int modelLayout,
                                        Class<VH> viewHolderClass,
                                        Query keyQuery,
                                        DatabaseReference dataRef)` constructor instead of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodCardViewHolder>(
                Food.class,
                R.layout.card_view_food,
                FoodCardViewHolder.class,
                foodInfoRef)`

Comment: Still, using `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` would require me to index my `ChatMessages` , a thing I have avoided. I have managed paginating my data, I just have an issue with the `ListView`